# How to access a desired path with filedialog.askopenfilename() in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

i have a simple function that i want to use to open a file dialog.

```
def open_music():
            filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
```

it by default opens my documents directory. i want it to allow me to access a music folder with in my D drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are almost there. Just give the value of initial directory (starting directory) using the `initialdir` attribute. Following is how you do it:

```
# I am just assuming that 'D:\Music' is the path to the directory
filename = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir='D:\Music')
```

If you get an error in the directory name above, try the following:

```
filename = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir='D://Music')
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()

def open():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='D:\Music', title="Select Music")
    print(filename)

button = Button(root, text="Open Music Folder in D Drive", command=open)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the job.

Comment: @HamzaBodla Glad to help. BTW you can make the answer accepted so it will help others to find the right answer.